# Date format from 2020.11.20 to 11/2020

Tags: abap

I'm trying to change the date format from 2020.11.20 to 11/2020

My objective is to remove the day and leave just month/year.
If I change the type of the field EDATU from vbep-EDATU to string it doesn't work.

Any tips on how to achieve my goal?

```
DATA: GR_COLUMNS TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE,
      GR_TABLE   TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_TABLE.


TYPES: BEGIN OF IT_STR,
         EDATU TYPE VBEP-EDATU,
         vbeln type vbep-vbeln,
       END OF IT_STR.

DATA: IT_FINAL TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF IT_STR.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <F_DAT> TYPE IT_STR.

SELECT EDATU vbeln FROM VBEP INTO TABLE IT_FINAL up to 10 rows.


LOOP AT IT_FINAL ASSIGNING <F_DAT>.

  <F_DAT>-EDATU = <F_DAT>-EDATU+4(2) && '/' && <F_DAT>-EDATU(4).

ENDLOOP.


TRY.
    CALL METHOD CL_SALV_TABLE=>FACTORY
      EXPORTING
        LIST_DISPLAY = IF_SALV_C_BOOL_SAP=>FALSE
      IMPORTING
        R_SALV_TABLE = GR_TABLE
      CHANGING
        T_TABLE      = IT_FINAL.

  CATCH CX_SALV_MSG .
ENDTRY.
GR_COLUMNS = GR_TABLE->GET_COLUMNS( ).

CALL METHOD GR_TABLE->DISPLAY.
```

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work, it’s a date field that you’re trying to update. You need a custom field of a string/char based type to store your value. The best way to do that is to a create a type.

Comment: But if, for example, I change the type from vbep-edatu to string I get this message "The database field EDATU or the result type of the aggregate function EDATU and the component "EDATU" of "IT_FINAL" are not compatible."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though a type D is really just a char based data type of length 8 it has some special behavior when outputting it. If you check in the debugger you will see the data in IT_FINAL is what you want, it's just that the ALV processes this data as a date regardless of the value in it.

So, for example date 20221019 got changed in IT_FINAL-EDATU to '10/2022'. Now, when you display it in the ALV it gets interpreted as a date and gets displayed depending on your user settings, assuming yours are yyyy.mm.dd the output would be: '10/2.02.2'.

You can get around this in two ways:

1. Add a new field to your table with a char-like type to hold the month value as suggested by Skin, and suppress the display of the EDATU field in the ALV

   ```
   gr_columns->get_column( columnname = 'EDATU'  )->set_technical( abap_true ).
   ```
2. Change the behavior of the EDATU column in the ALV by changing the edit mask with:

   ```
   gr_columns->get_column( columnname = 'EDATU'  )->set_edit_mask('_______').
   ```

Option 1 is clearly the better way to avoid unintended mishaps in the future.

Comment: 2 good options here suggested by Gert.  Either a buddy field to hold redundant data in form desired or hack the conversion exit / edit mask for display.  The 2nd option gets ugly if the field is to be editable ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new colum type C and changed the loop to

```
LOOP AT IT_FINAL ASSIGNING <F_DAT>.

  data(month) = <F_DAT>-EDATU+4(2).
  data(year) = <F_DAT>-EDATU(4).
  <f_dat>-char = month && '/' && year.

ENDLOOP.
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me.